# Why http links are not opening from default browser in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, firefox, browser

I have some browsers on my system i.e. Chrome, Mozilla and I.E.  Mozilla is the default browser. If I open any `http://` link it is not opening in Mozilla. Instead it opens an empty window in Chrome.

Q: Why it is not opening outside links with default browser (Mozilla) ?

[image: Set program associations screenshot]

Comment: Did you mean `http:\\\` or `http://` ?

Comment: @Hennes sorry its `http://`

Comment: What app are you trying to open from?

Comment: @digitxp for example I'm using any windows app and there is a link "click here to register". if chrome is default browser then it is opening link with chrome, but if mozilla is default browser even though it is opening chrome with blank page.

Answer (score 0):

On my version of firefox (52.0.2 (32-bit)) it cannot be set to own the .url 
or .website defaults.

- Firefox has 8 defaults available
- Chrome has 20 defaults available
- Edge has 9 defaults available
- Explorer has 15 defaults

I sequentially set all of them to my default and none could own the .url shortcut but explorer.

[image: Internet explorer keeps .url and .website defaults]